# Структура репозитория для решения из нескольких проектов

Tags: c#, git, git-submodule

Есть несколько проектов, которые постоянно модифицируются. Часть из них - библиотеки, которые используются в других проектах. 
Вопрос - как организовать репозиторий для этих проектов, что бы не было дублирования проектов?

Структура следующая (пунктирной линией показаны зависимости):

MainProject

|

| - - - - - DeviceConnectorProject - - - - SocketExtensions

| - - - - - SocketExtensions

SocketExtensions - проект-библиотека, содержащий частоиспользуемые функции в различных проектах (может исползоваться не только в MainProject);
DeviceConnectorProject - проект-библиотека, который использует функционал SocketExtensions (может исползоваться не только в MainProject);
MainProject - основной проект, в котором используется функционал SocketExtensions и DeviceConnectorProject.

Для каждого проекта заведен свой репозиторий. SocketExtensions не зависит ни от чего, с ним все понятно. 
DeviceConnectorProject зависит только от SocketExtensions, поэтому к его репозиторию SocketExtensions подключается как submodule.
Вопрос в следующем - в MainProject мне нужно использовать функции и SocketExtensionsProject и DeviceConnectorProject, если я подключу их как подмодули, то проект SocketExtensionsProject у меня будет продублирован дважды (один раз как подмодуль MainProject, второй - как подмодуль DeviceConnectorProject).
Наверное, в главном проекте можно было бы подключить подмодуль SocketExtensionsProject, взяв его из DeviceConnectorProject/SocketExtensionsProject.

Но как быть, если нужно подключить несколько библиотек как подмодули, использующих один и тот же проект?

Main

|
| - - - - - - ConnectorA - - - - SocketEx
|
| - - - - - - ConnectorB - - - - SocketEx
|
| - - - - - - SocketEx

Comment: Если вы работаете в компании, то вам можно поднять свой nuget сервер, а изолированные проекты каждый держать в своем репозитории и распространаять на другие проекты через nuget. Если вы работаете один и nuget поднимать смысла нет, то можно использовать  сабмодули git, храня проекты по прежнему отдельно в своих репозиториях.

Comment: Библиотеки вынести в отдельные репозитории, настроить сборку nuget-пакетов, подключать по необходимости в нужные решения. Если не хочется морочиться с пакетами - то можно и субмодулями оформить и отдельными репозиториями - это ни на что не влияет, просто нужно зафиксировать структуру каталогов/решений на диске, чтобы подключаемые проекты подключали проекты из известных мест.

Comment: @AK я так понимаю, мысли сходятся :)

Comment: @tym32167 Если использовать сабмодули, то проекты же будут дублироваться (см. последнюю структуру)? И ConnectorA использует сабмодуль SocketEx и ConnectorB использует тот же сабмодуль SocketEx. При добавлении ConnectorA и ConnectorB у каждого будет своя копия SocketEx? К тому же если SocketEx потребуется использовать в главном проекте, то уже третья копия проекта

Comment: Сабмодуль git - это ссылка на другой репозиторий, а не копия другого репозитория. У меня есть проекты, которые находятся в разных репах, но каждый из них через сабмодуль ссылается на третий репозиторий.

Comment: Вот, например, [проект](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient), а в нем [BattleNET @ 3d6dd03](https://github.com/tym32167/BattleNET/tree/3d6dd03aae74d8ec2b41056fe93877f78e6e264c) - это ссылка на коммит в [другом](https://github.com/tym32167/BattleNET) репозитории.

Comment: @tym32167 ссылка, но в рабочей же директории будет копия последнего коммита. Если подключены 2 подмодуля A и B, каждый из которых содержит один и тот же подмодуль LIB (одну и ту же ссылку на репозиторий), то в рабочей директории этих 2 подмодулей A и B будет своя копия подмодуля LIB. При изменении A/LIB нужно будет сначала запушить эти изменения, затем запулить их в B/LIB, иначе эти копии будут несогласованы

Comment: На жестком диске это будут да, копии. И это корректно, так как при изменении библиотеки, клиенты библтотеки (в нашем случае проекты, кто использует либу) должны использовать старую версию, пока прогер явно не обновит зависимости (сабмоули) - это сделано для того, что в случае какие то обратно несовместимых изменениях, все клиенты не попадали обвновившись автоматом. Такое же поведение будет и в nuget пакете, пока вы его руками не обновите, вы будете использовать старую версию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вкратце:

- перестаньте использовать git submodules, оформите отдельными репозиториями (строго: один проект = один репозиторий)
- рассмотрите возможность собирать nuget-пакеты

Подробнее.

Вы уже подошли к границе того, что ваше решение разрослось и пора перестать использовать один god-репозиторий для всего. Делите.

Студия умеет подцеплять проекты не только которые находятся в папке решения, но и выше по каталогу - просто нужно указать, где находится проект.

Насколько я понимаю, вы привыкли располагать модули внутри решений и если вдруг появляется потребность подключить где-то ещё - то и возникает вопросы.

Создавайте общие проекты сразу как отдельные узлы в папке git:

```
git

|
| - - ProjectA
| - - ProjectB
| - - ModuleA
| - - ModuleB
```

Или так:

```
git

|
| - - Projects | - - NameA
| - - - - - -  | - - NameB
| - - Modules  | - - Title1
| - - - - - -  | - - Title2
```

И оформляйте каждый проект и модуль как отдельный гит-репозиторий, вообще не использую git submodules.

Это половинчатое решение, вы можете либо остановиться на этом (если вам не особо критично, что все ваши проекты должны использовать одну и ту же версию общей библиотеки), либо оформить каждый модуль nuget-пакетом (даст возможность обновляться в разное время разным проектам и подключать разные версии общих библиотек).

Comment: относительные ссылки между репозиториями в файле солюшена? Вы серьезно? То есть для сборки вам надо склонировать 10 репозиториев в одну папку? Чем это лушче сабмодулей?

Comment: @tym32167 Нет, не в sln, а в csproj подключать относительные ссылки. Я предлагаю один раз склонировать каждый общий проект, специально же выделил минус (что будет одна и та же версия во всех проектах, куда подключат). Правильнее - уж доделать сборку пакетов.

Comment: в csproj  относительные ссылки на файлы с кодом?

Comment: правильно - либо сабмодули, либо nuget. То, что вы предлагаете, оно не правильно и я просто не могу понять преимуществ вашего решения.

Comment: @tym32167 сразу на другие проекты, хотя я и отдельные файлы пробовал подключать как ссылки (без физического дублирования файла). Потом правда настроил сборку пакетов.

Comment: @tym32167 Я пробовал субмодули гит, очень неудобная штука и впоследствии выпиливал, именно столкнувшись в подобных сценариях как у ТС. Проект топикстартера явно перерос стадию одного репозитория, пора двигаться в сторону расширения. Пробовать субмодули - это тупиковая ветка, боковая, потом всё равно придётся переделывать, а так хотя бы предложена структура, которая позволяет двигаться маленькими шажками, но в правильную сторону.

Comment: Как вы вообще с такой структурой смодете понять, что от чего зависит? Вот будет у вас 50 проектов и 50 модулей, проекты зависят от модулей, модули зависят от модулей, но как вы поймете, что от чего зависит? Вы будете регекспами парсить csproj?

Comment: это демагогия, я использую сабмодули, у меня проект собирается на тимсити, никаких проблем. Какие проблемы у вас? У ТСа пробьлема с обновлениями будет точно такаая же при использовании nuget, как и при использовании свбмодулей и это правильно

Comment: приходит новый разраб в команду и ему надо склонировать всё к себе даже для запуска одного из 50 проектов, так как никто не знает, что от чего зависит

Comment: кто то что то меняет, и все в команде должны пуллить изменения, так как если кто то заьбудет запулить один из 50 модулей, то его билд будет отличаться от билда на тот же самом тимсити

Comment: захочешь внедрить git feature branching в разработку, то не сможешь, так как буешь цкелыми днями разгребать в каких репах надо добавить ветку и потом как эту радость билдить на тимсити, если 27 проектов должны на develop глядеть, 8 на master и 15 на твою фичу-ветку

Comment: В первом же предложении под вопросом вы правильно описали, что нужно делать, если 50 проектов и десяток разработчиков - клепать nuget'ы. Судя по вопросам ТС ему нужна структура проектов для себя одного, поэтому я после того, как мы в комментариях дружно порекомендовали собирать пакеты оформил более подробно вариант со структурой каталогов.

Comment: ну, в моем понимании, ответ имеет бОльший вес, чем комментарий, потому я немного сагрился на ваше предложение с относительными ссылками, что по моему мнению, гораздо хуже сабмодулей :). Хорошо, что мы хотя бы сходимся в главном - вариант с nuget пакетами по идее самый лучший, хотя для 1 разработчика это может быть оверхед.

Comment: @tym32167 У вас было здравое зерно, поэтому я уже тоже подумывал об удалении ответа. Сабмодули у меня были в PHPшных проектах, там есть своя специфика, а .net проекты у меня сложены в один TFS и действительно живёт без проблем.

Comment: Я думаю, можно оставить все, как есть, пусть автор сам думает, что ему больше подхдит, мы уже всё расписали и разжевали :)